# Comparing a pointer to an integer in an if statement

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement

*result is set to return a boolean of either 0 or 1. What I want to do is have it log the statement below if result returns a value of 1.

My logs show that it is successfully logging a result of 1, howeever it isn't logging the 2nd statement, "All set, let's send you to MatchCenter". I'm not sure whether that 2nd if statement isn't in the right place, or the syntax just isn't correct. Any help is appreciated.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if (sender != self.nextButton) return;
    if (self.itemSearch.text.length > 0) {

        [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"eBayCategorySearch"
                           withParameters:@{@"item": self.itemSearch.text}
                                    block:^(NSString *result, NSError *error) {
                                        if (!error) {

                                            NSLog(@"The result is '%@'", result);

                                            if ((int)result == 1) {
                                                NSLog(@"All set, let's send you to MatchCenter");
                                            }

                                        }



                                    }];


    }

    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

}
```

Comment: Casting `result` to `int` is casting the pointer (memory address) to an `int`. That's not anywhere close to converting the text value to an `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `result` is an `NSString` which is either `@"0"` or `@"1"`?

In this case, to convert the string into an integer you would just do `[result intValue]`. Casting it like you are doing won't work.

```
if ([result intValue] == 1) 
{
    NSLog(@"All set, let's send you to MatchCenter");
}
```

Comment: Do not use property syntax to call a non-property method. Use `[result intVlaue]`.

Comment: Where would that go, before the 2nd if statement?